# Google Tag Manager PageView Trigger RegEx issue

Tags: regex, url, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a regex expression that will match the website homepage with these conditions (Brackets are for optional strings/characters):

```
Http(s)://(www.)example.com(/)(?parameter=value)
```

In core what it tries to do is:

- Include Http(s)
- Exclude all subdomains apart from www.
- Get the URL piece (This may be the root or a subdirectory)
- Include an optional trailing slash
- Include any parameters if exists

This is what I came up with:

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))(example\.com)|www\.(example\.com))((\/?\?\S*)|(\/?\s))
```

Every RegEx tester I try confirmes it is working (And I tried numerous other ways that were also working), but I'm having one single issue on my website:

I'm using this expression to fire tags in specific pages in GTM. But Google Analytics says the RegEx doesn't match the homepage.

It does work when there are parameters and all other portions are matching. Only the root domain does not for some reason when I update my GTM tag trigger.

https://example.com/ DOES NOT MATCH **(Problem here!)**

https://example.com/?parameter=value  MATCH (As intended)

https://example.com/child-page DOES NOT MATCH (As intended)

Where is the issue? I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Google/Regex they invented their own ? What is it's syntax ?

Comment: I don't think they invented their own. Maybe they have limitations of characters we can use etc. But I think that should effect anything since I use same stuff for both parameter version and clean version. It matches the parameter version but not the clean one

Comment: This is problematic `(?:www\.|(?!www))` What is the intent of this segment ?

Comment: The whole regex can be reduced to this `((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(example\.com))(\/?(?:\s|\?\S*))`

Comment: @x15 Thanks for the reply. But this regex also matches subdomains: https://subdomain.**example.com/**

Comment: This is to handle all combinations of https and www true false situations.

Comment: Possibly a "silly" question, but for my own clarity, are the targeted pages accessible via both https and http?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to match all the permutations mentioned  :

`((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(example\.com))(\/?(?:\?\S*|(?!\S)))`

https://regex101.com/r/YezL4h/1

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start) URL
      (?: https?:\/\/ )?
      (?: www \. )?
      ( example \. com )            # (2) Domain
 )                             # (1 end)
 (                             # (3 start) Parameters
      \/?
      (?:
           \? \S* 
        |  (?! \S )
      )
 )                             # (3 end)
```

*-----------------------*
If Moogle doesn't support assertions, then it is this :

`((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(example\.com))(\/?(?:\?\S*|(?:\s|$)))`

https://regex101.com/r/In57q6/1

Answer (score 0):

GTM Built in variables for web containers:
Page Hostname: Provides the hostname portion of the current URL.
Page Path: Provides the path portion of the current URL.
Page URL: Provides the full URL of the current page.

Specifying http(s) protocol is unnecessary if using Page Hostname variable.

Create a GTM Page View trigger - This trigger fires on - Some Page Views
Page Hostname > Matches Regex > `^(www\.)?example\.com$`
 + Page Path > Matches Regex > `^\/(\?.*)?$`
[image]

If http(s) does need to be specified, Page URL variable can be used:

GTM Page View trigger - This trigger fires on - Some Page Views
Page URL > Matches Regex > `^https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com(\/)?(\?.*)?$` 
[image]